# How to user TryUpdateModel on a web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have use the TryUpdateModel method on the controllers but now I need to use it on a web service (.asmx).

Have anybody achieve this?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: TryUpdateModel is part of the model binding of MVC. It doesn't really apply for an asmx service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TryUpdateModel method is part of ASP.NET MVC. You cannot use it outside. In a web service you don't need it because usually requests and responses are serialized into objects automatically.